# Silently passing exceptions with Future objects

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado, nonblocking, coroutine

I have a problem with silently passing exceptions in tornado while using futures in situations, when I am not explicitly waiting result from future coroutines (`yield some_future_obj`), such as infinite loop coroutine:

```
@gen.coroutine
def base_func():

    @gen.coroutine
    def tail_something():
        raise
        while True:
           yield some_other_coroutine

    base_func()
```

I have also noticed that this topic was already discussed: refer to [here](https://code.google.com/p/tulip/source/browse/tulip/futures.py#38) or [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/python-tornado/p7oxsm7q6hg/O-s0xwoAj-8J).
The problem is that if we don't wait for future completion explicitly, future.result() never be called and exception will never be raised. But tornado.concurrent is committed to use concurrent.futures package.

Now I just hang ioloop.add_future on current loop and simply execute log.exception(future.result()). But I don't like this approach, since it is a bit noisy (redundant lines in production code).

Please, contribute your ideas or may be a real answer.

Answer (score 4):

The reason Futures "hide" exceptions is that you have to decide *where* you want the exception to show up.  If you want to be able to handle the exception in your code, you must access its result somewhere (which in a Tornado coroutine means yielding it).  If you just want to log the exception, you can ask the IOLoop to do it for you:

```
IOLoop.instance().add_future(fut, lambda fut: fut.result())
```

Note that I'm just calling result() instead of logging its value.  This ensures that we don't log anything when there is no error, and the exception (with traceback) is logged by IOLoop's normal unhandled-exception machinery.

Comment: Thank you, very nice answer, Ben. I forgot that we can simply subscribe to any future's result.

Comment: what if coroutine is callback, that should be called every time when some data is ready to be processed. For instance, RabbitMq async consumer consumes messages from specified queue and receive all messages to some callback method like ``on_message`` which in turn must call some async code and wait for its reply. In such situation ``on_message`` is coroutine, but no way to handle exceptions there.

Comment: In that case you may need to insert a non-coroutine shim between RabbitMq and your real coroutine so you can get the coroutine's Future result and add it to the IOLoop.